# Can't get ImageView click event to work on Xamarin.Android widgets

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, widget

The last few days I've been trying to learn how to create widgets on Android Xamarin. I can't get the click events to work.

I know I need to make an Action, create an Intent, then create a PendingIntent with the created Intent. Then put the resource I want and use the PendingIntent with the method SetOnClickPendingIntent().

Here's the code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Appwidget;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Widget;
using GerirCalendario.Activities;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace GerirCalendario.Widgets.teste
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Label = "@string/widget_event_list_lbl")]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" })]
    [MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/widgetinfo")]
    public class WidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider
    {
        private static string NEW_EVENT    = "new_event";
        private static string LAUNCH_CAL   = "launch_cal";
        private static string REFRESH_CAL  = "refresh_cal";
        public  static string EXTRA_ITEM   = "extra_item";
        private static string TOAST_ACTION = "toast_action";

        private static int PENDING_NEW_EVENT   = 10;
        private static int PENDING_LAUNCH_CAL  = 20;
        private static int PENDING_REFRESH_CAL = 30;


        public override void OnDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
            base.OnDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
        }
        public override void OnDisabled(Context context)
        {
            base.OnDisabled(context);
        }
        public override void OnEnabled(Context context)
        {
            base.OnEnabled(context);
        }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(context);
            if (TOAST_ACTION.Equals(intent.Action))
            {
                int appWidgetId = intent.GetIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, AppWidgetManager.InvalidAppwidgetId);
                int viewIndex = intent.GetIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, 0);
                Toast.MakeText(context, "touched view " + viewIndex, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            else if (NEW_EVENT.Equals(intent.Action))
            {
                var pm = context.PackageManager;
                try
                {
                    var packageName = "com.android.settings";
                    var launchIntent = pm.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
                    context.StartActivity(launchIntent);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Something went wrong :)
                }
            }
            else if (LAUNCH_CAL.Equals(intent.Action))
            {
                var pm = context.PackageManager;
                try
                {
                    var packageName = "com.android.settings";
                    var launchIntent = pm.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
                    context.StartActivity(launchIntent);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Something went wrong :)
                }
            }

            //switch (intent.Action)
            //{
            //    case NEW_EVENT:  NewEvent(context); break;
            //    case LAUNCH_CAL: LauchCalendar(context); break;                    
            //}      

            base.OnReceive(context, intent);
        }
        private void LauchCalendar(Context context)
        {
            var pm = context.PackageManager;
            try
            {
                var launchIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(LauncherActivity));
                context.StartActivity(launchIntent);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Something went wrong 
            }
        }
        private void NewEvent(Context context)
        {
            var pm = context.PackageManager;
            try
            {
                var launchIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(CreateEventActivity));
                launchIntent.PutExtra(GerirUtils.INTENT_PICKED_DATE, DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
                launchIntent.PutExtra(GerirUtils.BACK_PRESS_TO, GerirUtils.BACK_TO_MainActivity);

                context.StartActivity(launchIntent);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Something went wrong 
            }
        }

        public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
            base.OnUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

            for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.Length; i++)
            {
                RemoteViews remoteViews = UpdateWidgetListView(context, appWidgetIds[i]);                
                appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
            }
        }


        private PendingIntent GetPendingSelfIntent(Context context, string action, int appWidgetId)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AppWidget));
            intent.SetAction(action);
            intent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, appWidgetId);
            return PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, PENDING_REFRESH_CAL, intent, 0);
        }            
        private PendingIntent GetPendingSelfIntent(Context context, string action, int pendingIntentId, int appWidgetIds)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AppWidget));
            intent.SetAction(action);
            intent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, appWidgetIds);
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            return PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, pendingIntentId, intent, 0);
        }        


        private RemoteViews UpdateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId)
        {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget_events_list);
            string PACKAGE_NAME = context.PackageName;

            #region ListView
            //Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(WidgetService));
            //svcIntent.SetPackage(PACKAGE_NAME);
            //svcIntent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, appWidgetId);
            //svcIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(svcIntent.ToUri(Android.Content.IntentUriType.AndroidAppScheme)));
            //
            //remoteViews.SetEmptyView(Resource.Id.listViewWidget, Resource.Id.empty_view);
            //remoteViews.SetRemoteAdapter(Resource.Id.listViewWidget, svcIntent);

            // Here we setup the intent which points to the StackViewService which will
            // provide the views for this collection.
            Intent listIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(WidgetService));
            listIntent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, appWidgetId);
            listIntent.SetPackage(context.PackageName);

            // When intents are compared, the extras are ignored, so we need to embed the extras
            // into the data so that the extras will not be ignored.

            listIntent.SetData(Uri.Parse(listIntent.ToUri(IntentUriType.Scheme)));
            remoteViews.SetRemoteAdapter(Resource.Id.listViewWidget, listIntent);

            // The empty view is displayed when the collection has no items. It should be a sibling
            // of the collection view.
            remoteViews.SetEmptyView(Resource.Id.listViewWidget, Resource.Id.empty_view);

            // Here we setup the a pending intent template. Individuals items of a collection
            // cannot setup their own pending intents, instead, the collection as a whole can
            // setup a pending intent template, and the individual items can set a fillInIntent
            // to create unique before on an item to item basis.
            Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(WidgetProvider));
            toastIntent.SetAction(WidgetProvider.TOAST_ACTION);
            toastIntent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, appWidgetId);
            toastIntent.SetData(Uri.Parse(toastIntent.ToUri(IntentUriType.Scheme)));
            PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.listViewWidget, toastPendingIntent);
            #endregion

            #region refresh calendar
            var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AppWidget));
            intent.SetAction(AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetUpdate);
            intent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, appWidgetId);

            // Register click event for the Background
            var piBackground = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widget_parent, piBackground);
            remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widget_toolbar_bg, piBackground);
            remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widget_refresh_img, piBackground);

            // Register click event for the Announcement-icon
            //remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widget_refresh_img, GetPendingSelfIntent(context, REFRESH_CAL, appWidgetId));
            #endregion

            #region toolbar items
            TextInfo ti = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
            var todayText = DateTime.Today.ToString("ddd, dd MMM").ToLower();

            remoteViews.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widget_today_text, ti.ToTitleCase(todayText));

            remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widget_add_event,
                GetPendingSelfIntent(context, NEW_EVENT, PENDING_NEW_EVENT, appWidgetId));

            remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.widget_today_text,
                GetPendingSelfIntent(context, LAUNCH_CAL, PENDING_LAUNCH_CAL, appWidgetId));
            #endregion

            return remoteViews;
        }       
    }
}
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorTransparent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorSemiTransparentBlack">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/widget_refresh_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/widget_add_event"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_today_white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_today_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/widget_refresh_img"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewWidget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="EMPTY"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone tell me if they see where or why the clicks arent working!?

Comment: You may refer to this: https://marcofolio.net/app-widget-xamarin-android/

Comment: Already did, can't make it work, I don't see what I'm doing wrong, I'll update the answer to what my codes looks like now, but it still doesn't work